# How to add spin.js to dialog

Tags: javascript, jsf-2

Apologize for this question but my knowledge in JavaScript is quite minimal.

After the user press the button a dialog will popup so I want to add the spin.js into the dialog.

Dialog jsf file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showStatus() {
        document.body.style.cursor = 'wait'; 
        statusDialog.show();
    }

    function hideStatus() {
        document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
        statusDialog.hide();
    }
</script>


<p:commandButton id="genButton" 
        value="Generate Files"
        widgetVar="startButton1" 
        disabled="#{נean.disableButton}" 
        actionListener="#{bean.generateUdm}" 
        onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(showStatus, hideStatus)"
        ajax="false"
        style="width:200px" 
        icon="ui-icon-shuffle">
    <p:fileDownload value="#{bean.streamedContent}"/>
</p:commandButton>


<p:dialog modal="true" header="Generating fILE" showHeader="true"
        position="center" 
        widgetVar="statusDialog" 
        draggable="false" 
        closable="false"
        resizable="false">

        ????????????? ADD SPIN ???????????
</p:dialog>
```

I manage to add the spin to my web app but not via the dialog.

I would appreciate to get some code example.

Comment: do you see any errors in js console ?

Answer (score -1):

If all that you want is adding loading image to dialog why don't you put a simple `gif` [(can get one from google](https://www.google.com/search?q=ajax%20image&hl=en&rlz=1C1CHEU_enIL465IL465&prmd=imvns&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=O5kLUN-fEpG5hAeu4tGGCg&ved=0CEUQ_AUoAQ&biw=1920&bih=912#hl=en&rlz=1C1CHEU_enIL465IL465&tbm=isch&q=ajax%20loading%20gif&revid=1493017729&sa=X&ei=R5kLUIKCLs-2hAehv4H4CQ&ved=0CEUQgxY&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=d6927dd21d265bd7&biw=1920&bih=912) Or generate one by your self [Ajaxload - Ajax loading gif generator](http://ajaxload.info/))

and use simple `<h:graphicImage` to show it...

[JSF 2 GraphicImage Example](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-graphicimage-example/)

?

Comment: No idea , what have you meant to say in your comment , but try to add appendToBody="true" to your dialog

Comment: The solution you suggest is working only in FireFox and Google Chrome , and I am not using ajax (see the attach code)

Comment: any chance you got nested forms ? Why don't you try a max simplified example from here http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=1616 ... and expand it to your current attempt... and on the way you might find the problem...

Comment: no I am not using nested forms and I did try to use the example you send (see my code in the question). try it yourself and see